# converting/constructing vector of tuples into heap

Tags: c++, vector, tuples, heap-memory

## **- Construction**

i constructed a vector of tuples `vector<tuple<int,int,int>> x`. For sake of simplicity, lets assume it is constructed it this way.

```
vector<tuple<int,int,int>> x;
for (int ii=0; ii < 10; ii++){
    for (int jj=0; jj < 10; jj++){
        currpeak[0] = ii + rand() % 10;
        currpeak[1] = jj + rand() % 10;
        currpeak[2] = rand() % 100;
        x.emplace_back(currpeak[0], currpeak[1], currpeak[2]);
    }
}
```

Now i want to get the n largest tuples, according to the 3rd element, and append them to another variable `vector<tuple<int,int,int>> y`. Lets assume `n=10`.

## **- Sorting**

Currently i am doing it this way : reverse sorting them, then choosing the first n elements.

```
// Sort them by 3rd element
bool sortbythird_desc(const tuple<int,int,int>& a, 
            const tuple<int,int,int>& b){
    return (get<2>(a) > get<2>(b)); 
}
sort(x.begin(), x.end(), sortbythird_desc);

// Extract the top 10 elements from x and put into y
vector<tuple<int,int,int>> y;
for(int jdx =0; jdx<10; jdx++){
    int curr_peak0=get<0>(x[jdx]);
    int curr_peak1=get<1>(x[jdx]);
    int curr_peak2=get<2>(x[jdx]);
    y.emplace_back(curr_peak0, curr_peak1, curr_peak2);
}
```

However this is `O(nlogn)` operations due to the sorting.

## **- Failed heap attempt**

If i can convert `x` to a heap, or even construct it as a heap from the beginning : `O(n)` operations. `pop_heap` : `O(log n)` times. In total it would take only `O(n + log n) = O(n)` operations. However the following fails

```
// Convert x to a heap
bool Comp(const tuple<int,int,int>& a){
    return get<2>(a); 
}
make_heap(x.begin(), x.end(), Comp);
```

Error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2197   'bool (__cdecl *)(const std::tuple<int,int,int> &)': too many arguments for call    Shash   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xutility    1481
```

How do i modify my code to convert x to a heap, or even to construct 1 in the first place ?

Comment: Take a look at `std::nth_element` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass a struct with the () operator. For example

```
struct Comp { 
    bool operator()(const tuple<int,int,int>& a, 
            const tuple<int,int,int>& b){
           return (get<2>(a) > get<2>(b)); 
    }
};
```

And pass this to `make_heap`

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just a note, i should be using '<' instead of '>' for it to be a max heap.
Now, i want to go further to construct the heap from the beginning, how do i replace the `x.emplace_back()`, do i simply use `x.push_heap()` ?

Comment: You can use `push_heap` or simply replace your vector with `priority_queue`, but `make_heap` is faster.