# constructing vector of tuples into heap

Tags: c++, vector, tuples, heap

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754378/converting-constructing-vector-of-tuples-into-heap), i am able to convert a vector of tuples into a heap.
However i want to go further back to construct tuples from scratch, eliminating the need to convert the vector.

How i previously constructed the vector is as follows:

```
vector<tuple<int,int,int>> x;
for (int ii=0; ii < 10; ii++){
    for (int jj=0; jj < 10; jj++){
        y[0] = ii + rand() % 10;
        y[1] = jj + rand() % 10;
        y[2] = rand() % 100;
        x.emplace_back(y[0], y[1], y[2]);
    }
}
```

How i have tried, to construct a heap from scratch

```
struct Comp { 
    bool operator()(const tuple<int,int,int>& a, 
            const tuple<int,int,int>& b){
           return (get<2>(a) < get<2>(b)); 
    }
};

vector<tuple<int,int,int>> x;

for (int ii=0; ii < 10; ii++){
    for (int jj=0; jj < 10; jj++){
        y[0] = ii + rand() % 10;
        y[1] = jj + rand() % 10;
        y[2] = rand() % 100;
        x.emplace_back(y[0], y[1], y[2]);
        push_heap(x.begin(), x.end(), Comp()); // using push_heap
    }
}
```

Errors on the `push_heap()` line :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2228   left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
Error (active)  E0153   expression must have class type
Error (active)  E0153   expression must have class type
Error   C2780   'void std::push_heap(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided
Error   C2672   'push_heap': no matching overloaded function found
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `x` as both the name of your heap and of your tuple. Plus `operator[]` isn't the way to access fields of a tuple.  Plus you are trying to create the heap multiple times

I guess you meant something like this

```
for (int ii=0; ii < 10; ii++){
    for (int jj=0; jj < 10; jj++){
        tuple<int,int,int> y;
        get<0>(y) = ii + rand() % 10;
        get<1>(y) = jj + rand() % 10;
        get<2>(y) = rand() % 100;
        x.emplace_back(y);
    }
}
push_heap(x.begin(), x.end(), Comp()); // using push_heap
```

Or even simpler this

```
for (int ii=0; ii < 10; ii++){
    for (int jj=0; jj < 10; jj++){
        x.emplace_back(ii + rand() % 10, jj + rand() % 10, rand() % 100);
    }
}
push_heap(x.begin(), x.end(), Comp()); // using push_heap
```

Comment: am i mistaken about the functionality of push_heap()? i am under the impression that it is a element-wise (per tuple) operation, hence i included it within the for loop.

Comment: Actually you are right, my carelessness was in `x.emplace_back(x[0], x[1], x[2]);` it should be `x.emplace_back(y[0], y[1], y[2]);` instead